Android parental control with weekly time limits
Do any of the parental control apps offer weekly time limits?
This would give the child the opportunity to learn to restrict their gaming, they can use it all up in one day or keep some for the next day.
Doing something daily makes it a habit, and we really do not want our child to form a gaming or a media-scrolling habit. This makes equal daily time-limits undesirable.
But then the alternative is to set gaming-days or youtube-days. Then if a friend wants to play outside the child has to choose between playing outside and forfeiting their gaming time or staying in and gaming. This is an unwanted situation.

see: link
